# td spacing with full border over tr

Tags: html-table

How can I create border-spacing and still cover the space with the same td color as shown in the image?
I want each row (tr) to get a background color that also covers the spacing between cells.
[image]

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  empty-cells: show;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
thead tr th {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1.125em 1.4375em;
}
tbody tr {
  background: rgba(22, 30, 41, 0.5);
}
tbody tr td {
  padding: 1.125em 1.4375em;
}
```

```html
<div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>role</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code that you have tried. So, it will be helpful to others for providing better solutions.

Comment: no, add the relevant code in your question. If your link dies - your question becomes worthless.